# RestKit 0.20.1 mapping local JSON "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key..."

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data, restkit

Hi—I'm using RestKit to map local JSON data (Twitter feed) that I've already received (which I've verified is happening), and am running into a problem when the mapping is taking place.  The error I'm receiving is:

```
2013-05-26 17:23:57.541 FoodTrucks[25932:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSEntityDescription 0x7663950> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tweet.'
```

From [my log (Gist)](https://gist.github.com/eroth/3ebfc5e12b594e63ac1d#file-gistfile1-txt), it appears as though it is finding mappable values (I have RestKit's ObjectMapping and CoreData logging turned on) from my JSON.  I've looked online a bunch to try and find out why it's receiving this error, but can't seem to find anything that applies to my situation.  This is how I perform the mapping:

```
-(void)performMapping
{
    RKEntityMapping *mapping = [ObjectMappings FoodTruckArticleMapping];
    RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[FoodTruckDataModel sharedDataModel] objectStore];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FoodTruck" inManagedObjectContext:store.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
    RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource *mappingDS = [[RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:store.mainQueueManagedObjectContext cache:store.managedObjectCache];
    mappingDS.operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    RKMappingOperation *operation = [[RKMappingOperation alloc] initWithSourceObject:self.moreStatuses destinationObject:entity mapping:mapping];
    operation.dataSource = mappingDS;
    NSError *error = nil;
    [operation performMapping:&error];
    [mappingDS.operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
}
```

I'm also not sure if this class that performs the mapping needs to inherit from anything in particular, and/or if it needs to possibly to adopt the `RKMappingOperationDelegate`.  Right now, it's just inheriting from a `NSObject`.  This is how my mapping class looks:

ObjectMappings.h:

```
@interface ObjectMappings : RKEntityMapping

+(RKEntityMapping *)FoodTruckArticleMapping;

@end
```

ObjectMappings.m:

```
@implementation ObjectMappings

+(RKEntityMapping *)FoodTruckArticleMapping
{
    RKEntityMapping *jsonMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"FoodTruck" inManagedObjectStore:[[FoodTruckDataModel sharedDataModel] objectStore]];
    jsonMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"tweetID"];

    [jsonMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"text": @"tweet", @"user.screen_name": @"foodTruckName", @"id_str": @"tweetID", @"created_at": @"timeStamp"}];

    return jsonMapping;
}

@end
```

And my object class is a `NSManagedObject` with all `@dynamic` method implementation.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

`NSManagedObject` class, FoodTruck.h:

```
@interface FoodTruck : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *foodTruckName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *tweet;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *timeStamp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *tweetID;

@end
```

FoodTruck.m

```
@implementation FoodTruck

@dynamic foodTruckName;
@dynamic tweet;
@dynamic timeStamp;
@dynamic tweetID;

@end
```

Comment: can you show the `NSManagedObject` subclass?

Comment: @Gabriele: Please see edit above.

Comment: How are you creating the destination object, foodTruck ?

Comment: @Wain- Sorry, I actually had a piece of wrong code up there.  It's now corrected and reads `RKMappingOperation *operation = [[RKMappingOperation alloc] initWithSourceObject:self.moreStatuses destinationObject:entity mapping:mapping];`.  My destination object is my `Food Truck` entity, as I believe you'd said to do in my previous post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out my problem— my error was not creating a new instance of a NSManagedObject that was initialized with my entity:

in `-(void)performMapping`

```
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:store.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
```

That NSManagedObject then becomes the destination object in RKMappingOperation, and not my entity, as I was doing before:

```
RKMappingOperation *operation = [[RKMappingOperation alloc] initWithSourceObject:self.moreStatuses destinationObject:newManagedObject mapping:mapping];
```

It's also necessary to call `-(BOOL)saveToPersistentStore:(NSError **)error` :
on your RKManagedObjectStore to save it to your SQLite database:

```
[store.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:&error];
```

That's something else that took me a while to figure out!